# JSONPath assert that element ist fully missing (not just null)

Tags: java, jsonpath, mockmvc

I'd like to assert that an element is completely missing from a JSON, not just `null`.

I.e. what is the JSONPath, that would match this JSON:

```
{ "key1": "abc" }
```

but not this:

```
{ "key1": "abc", "key2": null }
```

nor this:

```
{ "key1": "abc", "key2": "" }
```

with regards to `key2`?

For what it's worth, I'm using JSONPath with the Spring MockMVC framework, so any MockMVC ResultMatcher solution is also good.

Answer (score 1):

if you use MockMvc you can test your api and assert that field is missing in response like that:

```
mockMvc.perform(...).andExpect(jsonPath("$.key2").doesNotExist())
```